# Reset password expiration date to NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.5, role

We are cleaning out/standardising DB user/application accounts on the system that has a mix of accounts that were created using different commands at different times by different individuals.

We have a situation where for some of the accounts, the password expiration date attribute has been explicitly set to infinity and for some, it has not as per:

```
postgres=# \du+                                                                                    List of roles
    Role name     |                         Attributes                         | Member of |                                       Description
------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 user_1           |                                                            | {}        |
 user_2           |                                                            | {}        |
 user_3           | Password valid until infinity                              | {}        |
 user_4           | Password valid until infinity                              | {}        |
```

so that:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_shadow;
     usename    | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | userepl | usebypassrls |               passwd                | valuntil | useconfig
 ---------------+----------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------
  user_1        |    12345 | f           | f        | f       | f            | md5_foo                             |          |
  user_2        |    12346 | f           | f        | f       | f            | md5_foo                             |          |
  user_3        |    12347 | f           | f        | f       | f            | md5_bar                             | infinity |
  user_4        |    12348 | f           | f        | f       | f            | md5_bar                             | infinity |
 (4 rows)
```

and:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_roles;
     rolname    | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolbypassrls | rolconfig |  oid
 ---------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+-------
  user_1        | f        | f          | f             | f           | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           | 12345
  user_1        | f        | f          | f             | f           | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           | 12346
  user_1        | f        | f          | f             | f           | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    | infinity      | f            |           | 12347
  user_1        | f        | f          | f             | f           | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    | infinity      | f            |           | 12348
 (4 rows)
```

E.g.: `user_1` and `user_2` were created with:

```
CREATE USER user_1/2 WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'foo';
```

whereas `user_3` and `user_4` were created with:

```
CREATE USER user_3/4 WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'bar' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

We want to reset the `VALID UNTIL` attribute so that:

```
postgres=# \du+                                                                                    List of roles
     Role name     |                         Attributes                         | Member of |                                       Description
 ------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  user_1           |                                                            | {}        |
  user_2           |                                                            | {}        |
  user_3           |                                                            | {}        |
  user_4           |                                                            | {}        |
```

We have tried, unsuccessfully:

1. `ALTER ROLE user_1/2 WITH VALID UNTIL NULL;`
2. `ALTER ROLE user_1/2 WITH VALID UNTIL '';`
3. `ALTER ROLE user_1/2 WITH VALID UNTIL DEFAULT;`

So the question is, is it possible to reset the password expiration date role attribute to `NULL`/`DEFAULT`, preferably without having to recreate the role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been able to reset the password expiration date to `NULL` with:

```
UPDATE pg_authid
SET rolvaliduntil = NULL
WHERE rolname IN (
  SELECT rolname
  FROM pg_authid
  WHERE rolvaliduntil IS NOT NULL
);
```

That cleared the `Attributes` column for `user_1/2`.